# Ring contraction in benzilic rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, rearrangements

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzilic_acid_rearrangement) says that,

> Benzilic acid rearrangement occurs with ring contraction when used on cyclic diketones.

But gave no explanation, can you please elaborate on this with some mechanism. One such reaction I found [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/benzilic-acid-rearrengement.shtm), why ring contraction taking place?

Comment: Ultimately because it is energetically favourable and the resulting carboxylic acid can deprotonate giving a stable species that disfavours the reverse reaction.

Comment: @Waylander: Could you explain, why is the formation of a five-membered ring energetically favourable when it's more strained than a six-membered ring? Thanks!